# Opening specific image path and running script.py in windows terminal

Tags: python, image, path, format, command-prompt

Main Problem: Running the script.py file in terminal or windows command prompt.
I have been trying to run my script.py inside venv/Scripts in cmd but I don't know how and each time it won't work, though my code works and it creates a grey version of the image. When I switch my script.py outside the folder Scripts, I can run it in my PyCharm terminal, however the code won't work, it says file error. Can someone help me get this right, so i'll be able to understand it?

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
img = Image.open('./pokedex/charizard.jpeg')
filtered_img = img.convert('L')
filtered_img.save("grey.png", 'png')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you write here the error that appears when you run outside the Scripts folder?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.